# Find $\int_{C}\frac{e^{\pi z}}{\frac{(z-4i)^2}{z-i}}dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $C$ be $x^2+y^2=9$, oriented counterclockwise.

Find
$$\int_{C}\frac{e^{\pi z}}{\frac{(z-4i)^2}{z-i}}dz$$

It is easy to find the parameterization of $C$. However, when it comes to the integral, I don't know how to deal with $z$.

Comment: It appears you want to find $\int_C\frac{(z-i)e^{\pi z}}{(z-4i)^2}dz$. Check the integrand is analytic on and within $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Cauchy's differentiation formula and rearrange!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

So here we have $\int_C\frac{(z-i)e^{\pi z}}{(z-4i)^2}dz$ so we differentiate $e^{\pi z}$ once and multiply by ${\pi i}$ $\left(=\frac{2\pi i}{2!}\right)$.

We do not need to worry about the pole at $4i$ in this case since this does not lie within $C$.